# How to custom legend with react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a custom legend template in chartjs v3.3.0 like the image below. I can't seem to find any documentation in v3.3.0 for this option. Is it even available anymore? Can anyone show an example of how to accomplish this?

Here is my settings:

```
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      onClick: () => {
        console.log('do nothing');
      },
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        // generateLabels: (chart) => {
        //   console.log(chart.legend);
        //   return [1, 2];
        // },
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Gender',
      display: true,
    },
  },
},
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
  labels: defaultColors,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'label1',
      data: [1, 2],
      backgroundColor: getBackground,
      borderWidth: 0,
    },
  ],
},
width: 'auto',
height: '100%',
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsU12.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use htmlLegend if you want to render Customized Legend.

You can define plugin itself in a Pie plugins(as shown in code)or in Chart Configuration as shown in Chartjs 3x Documentation.

```js
 htmlLegendPlugin = {
 id: "htmlLegend",
 afterUpdate(chart) {
   const items = chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
   const ul = document.createElement("ul");
   items.forEach(item => {
     const li = document.createElement("li");
     const boxSpan = document.createElement("span");
     boxSpan.style.background = item.fillStyle;
     li.appendChild(boxSpan);
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.text));
     ul.appendChild(li);
   });
   const jsLegend = document.getElementById("js-legend");
   jsLegend.appendChild(ul);
 }
};
```

```js
<Pie data={data}
     options={option}
     height={400}
     redraw={true}
     plugins={[this.htmlLegendPlugin]}
/>
<div id='js-legend' className='whatever you wanna add'></div>
```

by this way your you can add custom css also to your legends.

P.S this is using React-chartjs-2.

Comment: `chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);` - here by they way labels are undefined in my case.
I also followed by the documentation :) 
Does anyone know the reason why it might happened?

Comment: Maybe the version of your react-chart-js is different